# Woocommerce Sort by Attribute Value

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, attributes

In my store I have a attribute called "pieces" that phpmyadmin lists as "pa_pieces" in wp_postmeta.
My store lists toys so I want to be able to sort it by the amount of pieces/the attribute. So by this I mean instead of sorting by price from low to high I want to add sort by number of pieces. It should be available on every shop page.

I found the code below online (actually very recent) and added it to functions.php and modified it for my taxonomy name. The name of my sort options shows up, but when I try to sort by it, it just shows "No products were found matching your selection."
I updated my products and every item contains at least 1 piece.

I know woocommerce/wordpress has a filter where I can filter to only show selected numbers of pieces. But with ~500 different values it isn't really an option.

I am thankful for any help.

```
/**
 * Save product attributes to post metadata when a product is saved.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The post ID.
 * @param post $post The post object.
 * @param bool $update Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
 *  
 * Refrence: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post
 */
function wh_save_product_custom_meta($post_id, $post, $update) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    // If this isn't a 'product' post, don't update it.
    if ($post_type != 'product')
        return;

    if (!empty($_POST['attribute_names']) && !empty($_POST['attribute_values'])) {
        $attribute_names = $_POST['attribute_names'];
        $attribute_values = $_POST['attribute_values'];
        foreach ($attribute_names as $key => $attribute_name) {
            switch ($attribute_name) {
                //for lenght (int)
                case 'pa_length':
                    if (!empty($attribute_values[$key][0])) {
                        update_post_meta($post_id, 'pa_length', $attribute_values[$key][0]);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wh_save_product_custom_meta', 10, 3);

/** 
 *  Main ordering logic for orderby attribute
 *  Refrence: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/custom-sorting-options-ascdesc/
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'wh_catalog_ordering_args');

function wh_catalog_ordering_args($args) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        switch ($_GET['orderby']) {
            //for attribute/taxonomy=pa_length
            case 'pa_length_asc' :
                $args['order'] = 'ASC';
                $args['meta_key'] = 'pa_length';
                $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
                break;
            case 'pa_length_desc' :
                $args['order'] = 'DESC';
                $args['meta_key'] = 'pa_length';
                $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
                break;
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

/**
 *  Lets add the created sorting order to the dropdown list.
 *  Refrence: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_catalog_orderby/
 */
//To under Default Product Sorting in Dashboard > WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'wh_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'wh_catalog_orderby');

function wh_catalog_orderby($sortby) {
    $sortby['pa_length_asc'] = 'Sort by pieces: Low - High';
    $sortby['pa_length_desc'] = 'Sort by pieces: High - Low';
    return $sortby;
}
```

Comment: Same issue here. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: If it is saying no results found, that suggests that your products don't have the metadata key you're trying to sort on. In the admin dashboard, go in to a product, unhide the additional fields, and check that the metadata is correct. Also, `$attribute_values[$key][0]` looks like it is giving you the ID rather than the value itself. Use `get_term( $my_id )->name` to get the value.